# Linux 'perf' instruction counter always returns 0

Tags: linux, perf

I'm currently trying to use `perf` to measure the # of instructions for a binary execution.

I used `perf stat -e instructions:u [binary]` to measure the instruction count, but it always returns 0, like below.

```
Performance counter stats for 'ls':

                 0      instructions:u                                              

       0.002080636 seconds time elapsed

       0.002325000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

I also tried `perf stat -e instructions:k [binary]` (kernel inst.) with various binary, but `perf` always returns 0 for instruction count.

FYI, I set `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` to `-1` in order to have `perf` to execute correctly.

Am I missing something here? I have no idea why `perf` returns 0 for every options/binary.

Or if there's any other solution to measure the executed instruction count, please let me know.

Comment: Are you running in a VM or something?  Works for me on running Linux 5.12.15 on bare metal, with a Skylake CPU, with `perf_event_paranoid` set to `0`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm running it on my VM. Is that the root cause why my perf is not working?

Comment: Most VMs don't virtualize the perf counters, so yes, that'd be the reason.  The VM might make it look like it worked to program them, but just have the values stay at 0 forever.